# How can I efficently use Matlab to find the all the variances along the third dimension of a 3D array?

Tags: matlab

If I have a matrix A of size `nx * ny * nz`, I could find the variances I'm looking for by using a double for loop:

```
varA = zeros(ny,nx);
for jj = 1:ny
  for ii = 1:nx
    varA(jj,ii) = var(A(jj,ii,:));
  end
end
```

However, I would very much like to avoid using this loop, as it can take a long time for large arrays. Is there an easy way to do this calculation efficiently in Matlab?

Answer (score 4):

You want to provide the [`dim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/var.html?refresh=true#inputarg_dim) input to [`var`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/var.html?refresh=true) to specify the dimension along which to apply the calculation.

```
varA = var(A, 0, 3);
```

You must specify the weighting scheme (the second argument) to be the default (0).

> **NOTE**: This dimension parameter is available for *many* simple calculations including `mean`, `std`, `diff`. Check the documentation for the specific function.